# List of unsolved problems of reverse engineering

Tags: pe, relocations

Decided to write out a list of still unsolved fundamental problems in the field of reverse engineering.

This means that today - there is no easy solution to these problems, or problems that can only be solved manually with a lot of effort and time.

1. Restoration of information about relocations (relocation at the
   level of COFF-objects, i.e. more detailed than regular
   fixups-relocations)
2. Extracting a linked static library from an PE-executables
3. Relocation of functions and sections within PE executables (if
   symbols and relocation information are removed from PE executables)

---

All these problems are mainly related to the lack of debugging information in pe-executables, therefore, I did not separate them into separate topics-questions.

Let me know if there is already a solution for at least one of these problems.